# Application bundle installation problem on Mavericks!

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, photos.app, imovie

I own a Macbook Pro in May, 2011 and got two DVD with it. One for installing OS X and another for Application Install. I'm currently running OS X Mavericks and now I want to install applications that came with my MBP (iPhoto, iMovie, iDVD, GarageBand, iWeb etc). The problem is ... I'm unable to install those from my DVD. It says ---

The installer could not install the software.

The installer could not install the software because there was no software found to install.

What can I do now? Suggestions or any help appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by Installing? just drag apps over to the hdd.

Comment: I know how to install apps on Mac. That's a pkg file.